# What is method for Redis function ZUNIONSTORE() at library phpredis?

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I use library **phpredis**.
What is alternative function in library **phpredis** for the native redis function **ZUNIONSTORE()**

Comment: I think it: zRevRangeByScore, zRangeByScore, zRange. What is function among these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the `ZUNION` method:

https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis#zunion

First parameter is output key.